# Why did the folder not clone too

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

So I have Visual Studio 2019 and Azure Devops as my repository.

I went to VS to clone the repo. Everything came with it except one folder. It was an authorization filter folder to filter authorization of a policy based authorization.

Why did that not get cloned?

Comment: Is the folder empty, from Git's perspective? I.e. are all the files in it matched by `.gitignore`?

Comment: What's the detail suffix of files in this folder? Better to add a screenshot here to make it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is just calling git clone command to clone the repo.

Suggest you could directly use Git Command, such as follow

```
git clone https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam C:\Repos\FabrikamFiber
```

If you still get the same result. Afraid these files `.xxx` are all ignored in Git by default. You need to check `.gitingore` file.

Either manually add them or override this for particular folders in your `.gitignore` file.